# KDE recent documents

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, desktop-environments, xdg

In KUbuntu in "Application Menu", there is the "Recent Documents" container-item:
[image: "Recent Documents" in KUbuntu]
I suppose other DEs also have something similar.

**What is the way to add there some document manually?**
(E.g. to put a `*.desktop` file into some specific folder, or to run some command similar to `xdg-open`, or etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enter `find ~ \( -type d -or -type f \) -iname '*recent*'` to get a list of files and directories that contain `recent`, `Recent`, `RECENT`, or some other case permutation thereof, in their names that exist in your home directory -- `-iname` means case insensitive name. Then, it would be a matter of inspecting the results one by one.

In my case (Debian Testing), it's in `~/.local/share/RecentDocuments`.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm also interested about some standardization (and *good* ways to do it). E.g. is `~/.local/share/RecentDocuments` standardized somewhere or just used de-facto in other environments? Are there some ways to manage it (e.g. console commands) except manually adding files? (I.e. I'm interested in both theory and practice, not only practice.)

Comment: Other environments use different things. In Cinnamon, for example, the list of recently accessed documents are kept in an XML file `.~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. What are you trying to do, exactly? It seems to me you're looking for a way to abuse the recent documents mechanism. There's no such thing as theory in this regard, only conventions. Every desktop environment has its own conventions.

Comment: Ok, now your answer seems to be full. I'll accept it (although it's better to specify that different DEs use different ways directly in the answer).

Comment: I'm looking to the way to manually add items in the cases when they're not added automatically (e.g. VirtualBox in KDE doesn't add recently-used virtual machines into the recent documents list). But, of course, I search for right ways to do it — rather than a dirty hack that will stop working tomorrow.

Comment: [Hmm...](http://askubuntu.com/q/809239#comment1222747_809239)

Answer (score 0):

All,

There are 3 categories of "Recents" that can be displayed. I personally switch 
to the "classic" menu view where these are easily displayed.  All there are 
added/deleted/modified in the "kdeglobals" file usually found at:

```
    ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals
```

and should contain these:

```
    [Recent Applications]
    MaxEntries=20
    UseRecent=true

    [Recent Documments]
    MaxEntries=25
    UseRecent=true

    [Recent Installed]
    MaxEntries=20
    UseRecent=true
```

Changing UseRecent true/false determines which show, but you'll notice the 
MaxEntries is set elsewhere, controllinng a "cat" or "trail" read of the 
containing  log file, so unless you find where to change that default "file 
read" you'll max at only 10 items read/displayed.

I'm hunting for that as you see I want to exceed the "10" limit.

Cheers!

OMR

Comment: Thanks for the bits of info. But how does it explain how to add an entry?